# Word for "collection of information used to make a decision"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that puts a portfolio, kit, packet, etc., in the context of being used for decision-making.

Examples of how this word may be used:

1. A mailer to inform voters about propositions they may vote on
2. A franchise kit, but using this word instead of "kit"

Comment: What's wrong with "Decision Kit", a kit for putting together a decision.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider '**dossier**'. Whilst it is usually used in a political or legal context, I think it does describe a collection of supporting documents that are collated in order to help make an informed decision about something.

From [Mirriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dossier)

> Dossier - a group of papers that contain detailed information about someone or something

Answer (score 2):

I would say ***guide***.

> a book, pamphlet, etc., giving information, instructions, or advice; handbook:
>   *an investment guide.*
>
> <sup>http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/guide</sup>
>
> something that provides a person with guiding information
>
> <sup>http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guide</sup>

A guide guides you. It helps you to make a decision. *Guide*, as a verb, has this meaning also.

> to help someone form an opinion or make a decision:
>
> <sup>http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/guide_2</sup>

Examples:

> Franchise Guide - Helpful information to make a confident investment decision
>
> <sup>https://www.canadianfranchisedirectory.ca/franchiseguide.aspx</sup>
>
> ---
>
> The Ministry has produced two election guides – one for voters and one for candidates – in order to make election information easier to find and more user-friendly.
>
> - 2014 Candidates' Guide for Ontario Municipal and School Board Elections
> - 2014 Voters' Guide for Ontario Municipal and School Board Elections
>
> <sup>http://www.mah.gov.on.ca/Page219.aspx</sup>

Answer (score 0):

DSS, Decision Support System, for one. There are other terms, other ways to look at it, depending on context.